# My model always fly up and fall down to the ground

Tags: control, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The moment I add my models to the world, they fly up to the sky and fall down to the ground. There is no force added to my models, however, it does fly up. Is there any parameter wrong of my models? What should I do to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17133/my-model-always-fly-up-and-fall-down-to-the-ground./) by [Ji Cai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3683/ji-cai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe your models collide with the ground plane when they're spawned. Consider to add a `Z` offset in its pose and try if that solves the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ji Cai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3683/ji-cai/) on 2017-08-31**:
Thank you! Your solution is right, it really helps!